# Two tables side by side without losing caption

Tags: tables, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to do two tables side by side. I have also benefited from the following thread, followed this answer and a couple of others. 
[Two tables side by side with minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325103/two-tables-side-by-side-with-minipage)

My code is the following

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}               
\usepackage{slashbox}   
\usepackage{subcaption}   
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}   

\def \hfillx {\hspace*{-\textwidth} \hfill} 


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
    \tiny       
            \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
        Cluster & MAE & MSE & E[over] & E[under] \\
        \hline
        1 & 0.31 &  0.48 & 2.00 & 1.38 \\
        2 & 0.32 &  0.49 & - & 1.36 \\
        3 & 0.26 &  0.44 & 1.57  & 1.50\\
        4 & 0.25 &  0.41 & 2.00  & 1.47 \\
        \hline            
        \end{tabular}    
        \caption{Caption1 that is long}
\label{subtable:pr1rnn}
 \end{subtable}%
   \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
   \tiny
         \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
        Cluster & MAE & MSE & E[over] & E[under] \\
        \hline
        1 & 0.40 &  0.59 & 1.50 & 1.28 \\
        2 & 0.51 &  0.82 & 1.44 & 1.44 \\
        3 & 0.53 &  0.77 & 1.31 & 1.31 \\
        4 & 0.41 &  0.62 & 1.88 & 1.28 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
             \caption{Caption2 that is long}
    \label{subtable:pr2rfres}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It gives me the following result:

[image]

I lose Caption 1 completely and the tables are not side-by-side. I tried to apply the answers from the related threads, but I can't seem to find where I am going wrong. How do I do them side by side?

Comment: You're missing the second mandatory argument of `subtable` so your example code does not compile but instead show the error message: `! Missing number, treated as zero.` The correct usage is `\begin{subtable}{<width>}` with `<width>`= `{.5\textwidth}` or any other length of your choice.

Comment: I had the {.5\textwidth}  command but when I typeset it, it doesn't see {.5\textwidth}  as a command. It just prints .5  on the screen just before the tables. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that represents the described behaviour. If I complete the code you posted with the documentclass `article` and a) the above described width, the desired layout is produced. If I complete the code b) without the width the above described error occurs. That said, I am not able to reproduce either of the outputs in your screenshots.

Comment: I am editing the question accordingly now.

Comment: I created a small file that only has the table and its output. All my packages are on the example now.

Comment: Thanks for posting a complete example. The code results in the following error message `! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
(subcaption) with the subfig package.` that tells you that the packages `subcaption` and `subfig` (that you both load) are incompatible with each other. As you currently use `subcaption`'s syntax, simply remove the `subfig` package from your preamble. Apart from that and unrelated to the problem, you load the `geometry` package twice with different options which will also lead to an error.

Comment: Thank you. At another page, I have two figures side by side. Removing `subfig` package affects them. Could I use these tables for subfigures?

Comment: The `subcaption` package offers the `subfigure` environment for this. The usage is similar to the `subtable` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that you like to have sub captions for each table ....

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
            \begin{tabular*}{0.9\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c c c}
        Cluster & MAE & MSE & E[over] & E[under] \\
        \hline
        1 & 0.31 &  0.48 & 2.00 & 1.38 \\
        2 & 0.32 &  0.49 & - & 1.36 \\
        3 & 0.26 &  0.44 & 1.57  & 1.50\\
        4 & 0.25 &  0.41 & 2.00  & 1.47 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular*}
        \caption{Caption1 that is long}
\label{subtable:pr1rnn}
 \end{subtable}%
   \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
   \centering
           \begin{tabular*}{0.9\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c c c}
        Cluster & MAE & MSE & E[over] & E[under] \\
        \hline
        1 & 0.40 &  0.59 & 1.50 & 1.28 \\
        2 & 0.51 &  0.82 & 1.44 & 1.44 \\
        3 & 0.53 &  0.77 & 1.31 & 1.31 \\
        4 & 0.41 &  0.62 & 1.88 & 1.28 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular*}
             \caption{Caption2 that is long}
    \label{subtable:pr2rfres}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

however, your mwe has problems with preamble. you cannot use in the `subfig` and `subcaption` in the same document. delete `subfig` package. and use the package `geometry` only once, if you really needed it.